# Making a parent node disappear using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have scripted a function that makes the parent of an element disappear but it does not work. Here is the code.
HTML:

```
<div class="att">
<p style="display:inline-block;margin-bottom:2px;cursor:default;">Delete Parent of this element by clicking the image!</p>
<img src="xicon.png" height="16" width="auto" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:3px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="deleteParent(this.id)"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function deleteParent(id){
document.getElementById(id).parentNode.style.display="none";
}
```

Why does this code not work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element doesn't have an `id`. You should just reference the element itself instead of by ID. This way it will work for all elements, without worrying bout whether or not they have IDs.

```js
function deleteParent(elem){
elem.parentNode.style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<div class="att">
<p style="display:inline-block;margin-bottom:2px;cursor:default;">Delete Parent of this element by clicking the image!</p>
<img onclick="deleteParent(this)" src="xicon.png" height="16" width="auto" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:3px;cursor:pointer;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

becuase you dont have any id in image set id and it will work see output

```js
function deleteParent(id){
document.getElementById(id).parentNode.style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<div class="att">
<p id='e' style="display:inline-block;margin-bottom:2px;cursor:default;">Delete Parent of this element by clicking the image!</p>
<img id='a' src="xicon.png" height="16" width="auto" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:3px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="deleteParent(this.id)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works, it is not as good of a solution as that presented by @Scimonster

Comment: yes @Scimonster's answer is better i just pointed out the mistake